# How to measure the degree of nonlinearity in regression model

Tags: nonlinear-regression

Could anyone guide me on how can we measure the curvature of nonlinear models?

I have to know the methodology to measure nonlinearity (both intrinsic and parametric) for nonlinear regression model. For example, if we have the nonlinear model y = f(x)+e 
then how we can say which type of nonlinearity  exists and what is the degree/amount of nonlinearity in the given model?

Comment: Are you only interested in the bivariate situation, so one x and one y, or in a multiple x situation? For the former take a look at distance correlation, maximum correlation or the maximum information coefficient.

Comment: thanks .i am interested in multivariate case.I want to know the method how to calculate degree of   nonlinearity